# SQS or Kinesis which one is good for queuing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

I have a server which can only process 20 request at a time. When lots of request coming, I want to store the request data, in some queues. and read a set of request (i.e 20) and process them by batch. What would be the ideal way to that ? Using SQS, or kinesis. I'm totally confused.

Comment: You probably want SQS. Read this https://sookocheff.com/post/aws/comparing-kinesis-and-sqs/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQS = Simple Queue Service is for queuing messages in a 1:1 (once the message is consumed, it is removed from the queue)

Kinesis = low latency, high volumetry data streaming ... typically for 1:N (many consumers of messages)

As Kinesis is also storing the data for a period of time, both are often confused, but their architectural patterns are totally different.

Queue => SQS.
Data Streams => Kinesis.

Taken from https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/faqs/ :

> Q: How does Amazon Kinesis Data Streams differ from Amazon SQS?
>
> Amazon Kinesis Data Streams enables real-time processing of streaming
>   big data. It provides ordering of records, as well as the ability to
>   read and/or replay records in the same order to multiple Amazon
>   Kinesis Applications. The Amazon Kinesis Client Library (KCL) delivers
>   all records for a given partition key to the same record processor,
>   making it easier to build multiple applications reading from the same
>   Amazon Kinesis data stream (for example, to perform counting,
>   aggregation, and filtering).
>
> Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS) offers a reliable, highly
>   scalable hosted queue for storing messages as they travel between
>   computers. Amazon SQS lets you easily move data between distributed
>   application components and helps you build applications in which
>   messages are processed independently (with message-level ack/fail
>   semantics), such as automated workflows.
>
> Q: When should I use Amazon Kinesis Data Streams, and when should I
>   use Amazon SQS?
>
> We recommend Amazon Kinesis Data Streams for use cases with
>   requirements that are similar to the following:
>
> - Routing related records to the same record processor (as in streaming MapReduce). For example, counting and aggregation are
>     simpler when all records for a given key are routed to the same record
>     processor.
> - Ordering of records. For example, you want to transfer log data from the application host to the processing/archival host while maintaining
>     the order of log statements.
> - Ability for multiple applications to consume the same stream concurrently. For example, you have one application that updates a
>     real-time dashboard and another that archives data to Amazon Redshift.
>     You want both applications to consume data from the same stream
>     concurrently and independently.
> - Ability to consume records in the same order a few hours later. For example, you have a billing application and an audit application that
>     runs a few hours behind the billing application. Because Amazon
>     Kinesis Data Streams stores data for up to 7 days, you can run the
>     audit application up to 7 days behind the billing application.
>
> We recommend Amazon SQS for use cases with requirements that are
>   similar to the following:
>
> - Messaging semantics (such as message-level ack/fail) and visibility timeout. For example, you have a queue of work items and want to track
>     the successful completion of each item independently. Amazon SQS
>     tracks the ack/fail, so the application does not have to maintain a
>     persistent checkpoint/cursor. Amazon SQS will delete acked messages
>     and redeliver failed messages after a configured visibility timeout.
> - Individual message delay. For example, you have a job queue and need to schedule individual jobs with a delay. With Amazon SQS, you can
>     configure individual messages to have a delay of up to 15 minutes.
> - Dynamically increasing concurrency/throughput at read time. For example, you have a work queue and want to add more readers until the
>     backlog is cleared. With Amazon Kinesis Data Streams, you can scale up
>     to a sufficient number of shards (note, however, that you'll need to
>     provision enough shards ahead of time).
> - Leveraging Amazon SQS’s ability to scale transparently. For example, you buffer requests and the load changes as a result of occasional
>     load spikes or the natural growth of your business. Because each
>     buffered request can be processed independently, Amazon SQS can scale
>     transparently to handle the load without any provisioning instructions
>     from you.

Comment: How much faster for processing data is kinesis vs sqs?